# Running sublime commands

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there a way to run a sublimetext command (ie, the built-in commands documented [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/commands.html) or added) without creating a keybinding or adding something to the pallette and `.sublime-commands`?

I've tried running `sublime.run_command` from the console to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Right before posting I realized I should be using the local `window` instance.

Opening the python console with `` ctrl+` `` and run the command using the current instance `window.run_command("<command>", args=<args>)` is a workable solution.

(posting anyways because I was unable to find an answer to my question)

Comment: Note that this is only true if the plugin is subclassed from `sublime.WindowCommand`. A `sublime.TextCommand` runs fine with `sublime.run_command(...)` or `view.run_command(...)`.